# Windows 10 display freezes after 100% cpu utilization for few seconds

Tags: windows, operating-system, windows-10, freeze, cpu-usage

Windows 10 system is freezing after cpu utilization reaches to 100% for few seconds, but when I remove VGA cable and insert it back it starts working, also when windows freeze caps and num locks lights are blinking.

What should I do to analyze reason. I have checked bios, graphics driver updates.

Comment: This question is not about programming, so it does not belong to this site